# What browsers currently support JavaScript's 'let' keyword?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox3.6

I'm developing an app and don't have to ever worry about Internet Explorer and was looking into some of the features present in A+ grade browsers that aren't in Internet Explorer1.

One of these features I wanted to play around with is [JavaScript's let keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#let_definitions)

I can't seem to get any of their 'let' examples to work in Firefox 3.6 ([User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP) string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)). I get `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` when executing `let foo = "bar"`.

So, what browsers support the let keyword? (Or am I doing something wrong?)

Comment: While and understand and agree your not-caring-if-it-works on IE, you should consider that the "let" keyword is mozilla-only, so even if it's ok to say "IE doesn't support it", the proper way to say it, would be "only mozilla supports it".  Just like we avoid IE-only tags, or keywords, you should avoid and *-only keywords.

Comment: Hugo, you need to keep in mind that HTML, CSS, JS isn't a web-only platform anymore. The code happens to be code that will never run in any version of IE, or any *web*browser, for that matter. :-)

Comment: What on earth is Apple trying to do.. it's 2015 and no signs of `let` support in their pathetic browser.

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE** Many of the older answers (including the accepted answer) have been overtaken by events. All major up-to-date browsers support the ES2015 (aka "ES6") `let` keyword, but as of this writing support is fairly new in some circles (only iOS 10 Safari, for instance).

Comment: I suggest changing your accepted answer to one of the now-correct ones. Yes, the currently-accepted one was correct at the time, but it's been incorrect for several years now, and the purpose of SO is to be a repository of knowledge, not a historical archive. :-)

Comment: How was this question asked in 2010? I thought `let` and `const` were introduced in 2015 with `es6`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**EDIT**: `let` and `const` are supported by all modern browsers and are part of the [ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) specification.

Basically if you don't need to support anything below IE11, `let` and `const` are safe to use nowadays.

On *IE11* there's a small quirk with `let` when used with `for` loops, the variable is not  bound to the `for` block as you would expect, it behaves as `var` did...

See also: [let](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) and [const](https://caniuse.com/#feat=const) support.

---

**Old and outdated answer from 2010:**
Those extensions are not ECMA-Standard, they are supported only by the Mozilla implementation.

On browser environments you should include the JavaScript *version number* in your `script` tag to use it:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">  
  var x = 5;
  var y = 0;

  let (x = x+10, y = 12) {
    alert(x+y + "\n");
  }

  alert((x + y) + "\n");
</script>
```

Comment: Well; I just updated my answer and then found out that you beat me in a minute ;). +1

Comment: Thanks, I was using the HTML 5's '<script></script>' without the type attr.

Comment: Note that the `let` keyword *is* now in the ECMAscript 6 (draft) standard.

Comment: Can be enabled in Chrome 19+ via "Experimental Javascript features" flag and in node.js using `--harmony`.

Comment: Is `;version=1.7` still required in Firefox? I tried `let` in the console and it worked.

Comment: Seems like this version specification is deprecated now. If I try to specify version, Chrome is not loading that javascript.

Answer (score 34):

As of April 2017:

- All up-to-date major browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, and Edge support the ES2015 (aka "ES6") `let` keyword.
- iOS Safari did not support `let` until OS 10 (e.g, OS 9 did not).
- Some older browsers, such as IE9-IE11, support an early version of `let` but **don't** support the semantics defined by ES2015 (particularly in relation to declarations in the headers of `for` loops). So it's not a syntax error, and it does declare the variable, but it doesn't work the way it's supposed to. For instance, in a correct implementation, the following logs 0, 1, and 2; on IE9-IE11, it logs 3, 3, 3:

  ```js
   for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
         }, i * 100);
    }
  ```
- Obsolete browsers such as IE8 do not support it at all.

Answer (score 25):

There is partial support in Internet Explorer 11 ([`for` scope is incorrect](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let)) and full support in all current browsers ([ECMAScript 6 compatibility table: let](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let)).

Comment: While IE11 does "support" the `let` keyword (in that it doesn't throw a `SyntaxError`), its implementation does not conform to the spec - the variable is not properly block-scoped. (also note that there is not and will never be any IE past 11)

Answer (score 12):

Internet Explorer and [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) don't support `let` on any browser version, Firefox since version 2.0 and Safari since 3.2.

See this [JavaScript version table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions) on Wikipedia.

[I just found out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_javascript_1.7) that you need to define whether you use JavaScript 1.7 or not. So your code will be:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"> ... </script>
```

Comment: Seems like this version specification is deprecated now. If I try to specify version, Chrome is not loading that javascript.

Comment: The information regarding to browser version support is outdated.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently [Internet Explorer 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10) in [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) mode supports `let`, per *[JavaScript Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/s4esdbwz(v=vs.94).aspx)*.

Answer (score 3):

A great deal of time has passed since this question was first asked: the 'let' and 'const' keywords have been introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Search for 'let' or 'const' in this awesome ES6 compatibility table:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 2):

Just an update: Chrome now supports `let` but only if you declare the `"use strict"`; directive.