# Javascript: closure of loop?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

I would like to do the something along the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    createButton(x, y, function() { alert("button " + i + " pressed"); }
}
```

The problem with this is that I always get the final value of `i` because Javascript's closure is not by-value.
So how can I do this with javascript?

Comment: You could edit createButton, allowing it to have another argument passed, that is, i. This way you can store i in your createButton function and use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        createButton(function() { alert("button " + i + " pressed"); });
    })(i);
}
```

Note that JSLint doesn't like this pattern. It throws "Don't make functions within a loop.".

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/ZKeXX/

Comment: I like this answer more than Peter's due to its cleanliness. It would be nice if more browsers supported the `let` keyword though.

Comment: @McStretch I tried to make a `let` demo in jsFiddle, but I couldn't make it work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/ZKeXX/1/ Firefox 4 throws an error.

Comment: @Šime - I just saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356830/what-browsers-currently-support-javascripts-let-keyword , which says you have to explicitly tell the browser (Firefox only right now) that you're using 1.7. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/ZKeXX/1/. Pretty lame huh? Obviously not really a good solution until everyone supports 1.7 or higher, and who know when that will happen.

Comment: @McStretch I see. The updated demo (which works in Firefox) is here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/ZKeXX/2/ It seems that we won't be able to use `let` for a long time. Even if IE10 implements it, we'd have to wait until IE9 exits the market (and that may not happen before 2020).

Answer (score 7):

One solution, if you're coding for a browser that uses JavaScript 1.7 or higher, is to use the `let` keyword:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    let index = i;
    createButton(x, y, function() { alert("button " + index + " pressed"); }
}
```

From the MDC Doc Center:

> The let keyword causes the item
>   variable to be created with block
>   level scope, causing a new reference
>   to be created for each iteration of
>   the for loop. This means that a
>   separate variable is captured for each
>   closure, solving the problem caused by
>   the shared environment.

Check out the [MDC Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) for the traditional approach (creating another closure).

Answer (score 4):

Create a new scope for the closure by executing another function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    createButton(x,y, function(value) { return function() { alert(...); }; }(i));
}
```

http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: 1. You might want to place a semi-colon at the end of the return statement to make the code a bit more readable. 2. IIFE's are usually wrapped in parens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the closure into a separate function.

```
for(var dontUse = 0; dontUse < 10; ++dontUse) {
    (function(i) {
        createButton(x, y, function() { alert("button " + i + " pressed"); }
    })(dontUse);
}
```

Thise code creates an anonymous function that takes `i` as a parameter for each iteration of the loop.
Since this anonymous function has a separate `i` parameter for each iteration, it fixes the problem.

This is equivalent to

```
function createIndexedButton(i) {
    createButton(x, y, function() { alert("button " + i + " pressed"); }
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    createIndexedButton(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    createButton(x, y, (function(n) {
        return function() {
            alert("button " + n + " pressed");
        }
    }(i));
}
```

The anonymous function on the outside is automatically invoked and creates a new closure with `n` in its scope, where that takes the *then current* value of `i` each time it's invoked.