# javascript closure in a for loop

Tags: javascript, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
>   [Javascript: closure of loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555464/javascript-closure-of-loop)

so I would like the results to be 1,2,3 instead of 3,3,3.  How do I set the context/scope so that the jobs are using the correctly scoped "i"?

```
function buildJobs(list) {
  var jobs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
    jobs.push( function() {alert(item)} );
  }
  return jobs;
}

function testJobs() {
  var jobs = buildJobs([1,2,3]);
  for (var j = 0; j < jobs.length; j++) {
    jobs[j]();
  }
}
```

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but same idea.

Comment: @hvgotcodes well there are over 9000 exact duplicates so it doesn't really matter if that one isn't :D

Comment: precisely, its amazing how many times this question gets asked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the inner function with a another function that's immediately executed and receives `i` as an argument:

```
function buildJobs(list) {
  var jobs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
    (function(i) {
      jobs.push( function() {alert(list[i])} );
    })(i);
  }
  return jobs;
}
```

You're now closing over the `i` that is local to the wrapper function, which is a different variable in each iteration. (In your original configuration each inner function was closing over the *same* variable (whose value was `3` by the time any of the functions ever executed).)

Answer (score 1):

When loops generate functions, they all share access to the same scope of variables.  And there can only be one variable on the same name in a given scope.  So they all use `i` from the loop, and use the current value of `i` when they execute.  And after the loop runs, it will always be 3.

```
function buildJobs(list) {
  var jobs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var item = list[i];
      jobs.push( function() {alert(item)} );
    })(i);
  }
  return jobs;
}
```

So introduce a new scope that captures the current value of `i` just for that iteration.  You now have a new scope for each function generated, each with a different value for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildJobs(list) {
    var jobs = [];

    list.forEach( function( item ){
        jobs.push( function(){
            alert(item);
        });
    });

    return jobs;
}
```

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)