# Why can't I set mass event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So these two work fine:

```
$(document).on("click", "#_something", function(){
    $('#vid').attr('src',video_config["something"].video);

});
$(document).on("click", "#_anotherthing", function(){
    $('#vid').attr('src',video_config["anotherthing"].video);

});
```

However, `something` and `nothing` are properties of an object I made, so I attempted to do this:

```
for (var key in video_list){
    $(document).on("click", "#_"+key, function(){
        $('#vid').attr('src',video_list[key].video);
    });
}
```

Which sort of messed it up, and set all the `src` values to the last `video_list[key].video` value I have. To rephrase, this assigned all of the `src` properties the same value.

How do I do this correctly without manually writing each of the event handlers?

Comment: Use classes instead of id's.

Comment: having more than one #vid will mess things up

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same id? This is highly discouraged in general.

Comment: Nope, there is only one `#vidSrc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your Handler function captures the `key` variable which is scoped to the parent function. When your Handler executes, `key` has the last value.

The fix is to capture the current value at each iteration by using yet another function scope. Like this:

```
for (var k in video_list) {
  function(key) {
    // create your event handler here using key
  }(k);
}
```

This is explained in this question that is basically the same as this one:
[javascript closure in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661376/javascript-closure-in-a-for-loop)

In ES6 browsers, `let` being block scoped you can use it as a shortcut:

```
for (let k in video_list) {
  let key = k;
  // same code as your question goes here, using key.
}
```

Comment: `let` is not supported in most browsers

Comment: That's why I said _in ES6 browsers_. Also, _most_ browsers depends on your target audience: it's supported by IE11+, at least FF24+ and at least Chrome 30+. For those ES6 compatibility things you can look at Kangax compatibility tables: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#let

Comment: What's your browser? IE11 here, your fiddle works perfectly, no error. But the output is 333, so now I know. I'll fix my answer with this experiment, thanks!

Comment: It didn't work with FF 27.0.1 and Chrome 33.0.1750.154 (these are the ones I have installed)

Comment: Regarding FF, it's supported since FF 2, which supports Javascript 1.7. The trick is that you have to opt-in JS 1.7 support by using `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">`. Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7

Comment: That's a neat trick. It worked in FF, but still not in chrome.

Comment: Not 100% sure about Chrome but I guess it's still enabled by an experimental switch in chrome://flags. That's a pity because you can't assume your users enable experimental switches :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way using one event handler, a class and a data attribute:

```
$(document).on("click", ".video", function(){
    var key = $(this).data("key"); // in the element add data-key="xyz"
    $('#vid').attr('src',video_list[key].video);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty hack:

```
for (var key in video_list){
    (function(key){// create a new context, so not all handlers point the the same key
        $(document).on("click", "#_"+key, function(){
            $('#vidSrc').attr('src',video_list[key].video);
        });
    })(key);
}
```

The correct way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-new-class-you-just-defined", function() {
    $(this).attr('src', video_list[$(this).attr('id').slice(1)].video);
});
```

EDIT: Add substring to the id. It's better to have some sort of lookup mechanism, rather than storing this in id's, as @jods suggested.

Comment: Your second piece of code is not correct because `id` starts with an additional underscore `_` rather than the raw property name. A bit of fiddling around is required. It's quite hacky, if you go this route you ought to put the property name in an additional attribute, like `data-videokey=something`.

Comment: @jods You are correct. I was focusing on the loop and missed this.