# Javascript - Avoiding (the effects of) closures

Tags: javascript, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Javascript: closure of loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555464/javascript-closure-of-loop)

I'm having some issues with javascript closures that I can't wrap my head around... I usually find them really useful, but this time they're getting in my way.

#### My problem

I have a list of objects containing some information - let's call it `infos`. Each object in `infos` has a string property `text`, and a property `control` which references a control object. The control object has (among other things), a function property `activate`. An example of an object in `infos` could look like this:

```
var info = { 
    text: 'Some string', 
    control: { 
        activate: function() { 
            alert('activated!'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to loop through `infos` and create some new objects (actually, a DOM element, using jQuery) based on the information in the `info` object.

I've tried something like this:

```
for (var i in infos) {
    $('<a>')
        .attr('href', '#')
        .text(infos[i].text)
        .click(function() {
            infos[i].control.activate(); // This is where I get problems
        });
}
```

Now, when executing the click handler, something (in the example above usually the variable `i`) is `undefined`, which causes an exception.

I have also tried the following variant:

```
for (var i in infos) {
    var ctrl = infos[i].control;
    $('<a>')
        .attr('href', '#')
        .text(infos[i].text)
        .click(function() {
            ctrl.activate(); // This is where I get problems
        });
}
```

In this case I don't get any exception, but regardless of which item I click, it is always the last control that is activated.

#### My understanding of this, so far

If I've understood javascript closures correctly, this is because when the click handler function (in the second code snippet) is created with a closure that has pointers to the variables defined at the point of defining this function - `infos` and `i` in the first example, in addition to `ctrl` in the second.

I think I could be able to resolve this, if I was able to *"avoid the closure"*; in other words, I'd like to refer the variables with their values as they were at the point of *declaring* the click handler function, rather than at the point of its *execution*.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or, perhaps, an even better solution to this problem?

Comment: Also, please note that the control is not declared at the point of defining the `info` object, so I can't define an `activate()` method directly on the `info` object itself. It would give me exactly the same problems.

Comment: This is a common question. You need an *additional* closure, used inside the loop. Use this code: `$.each(infos, function(i,value){ ...logic... });`

Comment: @RobW: My (quite quick) searches here on SO and on Google did not give me anything of use. Would you care to expand on how to do that, or link me to a possible duplicate on SO? That would be most helpful =)

Comment: There we go. On a side-note, you should not use `for(var i in arr)` to iterate over an array. Use a proper `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` loop for it!

Comment: @TomasLycken I had edited my comment to include the solution for your specific case.

Comment: @RobW: Thanks a lot! I'll try that out at once!

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I've never heard about for-in loops over arrays this being an antipattern. Why is it bad? Is there any further reason than the fact that it might be confusing to a future reader (as outlined at the bottom of [this post](http://jaysoo.ca/2010/05/06/javascript-anti-patterns/))?

Comment: One reason is that there is no guaranteed order for property enumeration. Another one is that it breaks when someone extends `Array.prototype`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I don't think the first argument is valid for the case "for-in loops *over arrays*", but I definitely agree with the second. I'll start using `$.each()` from now on =)