# Javascript - Only in IE it gives me "Expected identifier"

Tags: javascript, firebase, internet-explorer, firebase-realtime-database

I've tested the following code on every browser, and only Internet explorer says its expect an identifier. I've been through many sites but i cant find the answer by myself.

```
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("products");
ref.once("value",  function(snapshot)  {

   let profiles2 = []
      snapshot.forEach( function(profile) {
       let {url,mobile2} = profile.val();
        profiles2.push({url,mobile2}) 
})
})
```

Im glad for every answer!

Comment: What happens if you directly do profiles2.push(profile.val();})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to IE not supporting ES6 fully. You can use babel to compile your code to ES5 to make sure it is supported by all browsers.

[What browsers currently support JavaScript's 'let' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356830/what-browsers-currently-support-javascripts-let-keyword)

Comment: Hey, let worked but you were right i just had to copy & paste the code on: https://babeljs.io/repl/